# Is it possible to bypass phpBB login or even disable it...?

Tags: php

I am trying to use a forum with my website. Those who haven't registered with my site can register only with the forum. But, those who have an account with my site must be automatically logged in to the forum as well. How is that to be done...???

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but what you are looking for is called "Single Sign On". AFAIK, there are SSO solutions for phpBB - maybe worth Googleing....

Comment: could you please tell me more about that...???

Comment: @sandeepan: Have got a hint about urs. But could you please elaborate a little bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to disable phpbb's login. Just call it's login function when needed (when the user is logged into your site).

Like this:-

```
<?php
/* Example 1: Logging in place in your pages

*/

if($_SESSION['userLoggedinMySite'] && !$_SESSION['userLoggedintoForum'])
{
      $username = $_SESSION['username'];
      $user_password = $_SESSION['user_password'];


      //Write code to login user to your system here
      //Write code to login user to phpbb here (follow code of phpbb's ucp.php)


      //Setting forum session login flag to avoid repeated login attempts
      $_SESSION['userLoggedintoForum'] = true;  

}
?>
```

Check the file ucp.php in the root of the phpbb installation. Inside that file there are cases for `login`, `register` and all similar things. Looks like these are executed in case of normal login/register of phpbb (through login form post - as given in  [Practical External login](http://wiki.phpbb.com/display/MODDOCS/Practical.External+login). As you have it installed, try playing with the code logic (printing the variables that are passed) in case of normal form login so as to be sure what data you need for calling the phpbb login function, then modify it to the logic I wrote.

Comment: @sandeepan: Have got a hint about urs. But could you please elaborate a little bit....

Comment: @Kailash added a condition in the code to check if the user is logged into your system but not in the forum. In that case the above code will login the user to phpbb forum. If you have newly installed phpbb to your site, the old users will not be there in the forum's user database. Are you having a users table of your own? In that case you may need to import the users from your database into the phpbb database.

Comment: @sandeepan: Yes.. I am having my own users database. all i need is to auto login user's to the forums on loggin into my site. my website and the forum were created at the same time.. Also the forum can be viewed by even those who haven;t registered with my site.

Comment: @sandeepan: also suppose there is a new user who registers with my site, how is that i add him even to the forums table...

Comment: @Kailash, I am sure there will be a function like `PHPBB_Register()` in the library's code. I have not worked on phpbb. You just have to call that function with the values when your site's registration code completes successfully and it will add to the forum's table. Just be sure that you call the library's defined functions for doing operations like this and not your own code to enter data into phpbb's tables.

Comment: @Kailash you are welcome. answering questions is a great way of improving knowledge fast. I am enjoying it.

Comment: @sandeepan: but the file phpbb_login2.php does not exist

Comment: @Kailash sorry I just put some code which I found. This phpbb_login2.php must be that user's own project's file. But now I checked some other places. Check my update.